# Unable to cast object when LINQ query ToList() cast to a specific List<T> subclass

Tags: c#

I am getting a runtime exception and can't figure out why

> Unable to cast object of type
>       'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Foo.ElementNameViewModel]'
>       to type
>       'Foo.ElementNameList'.

The classes I have are

**ElementNameList** - a list of a particular type

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class ElementNameList : List<ElementNameViewModel> {}
}
```

**ElementNameViewModel** - an item to be in a list

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class ElementNameViewModel
    {
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the exception occurs in a controller at

```
var elements = (ElementNameList) db.Elements
            .Select(c => new ElementNameViewModel
            {
                Symbol = c.Symbol,
                Name = c.Name
            })
            .OrderBy(e => e.Symbol)
            .ToList();
```

Not sure how I should refactor the elements list if subclassing List is not done.

Comment: Usually inheriting `List<T>` is a bad idea, what are you trying to accomplish here?  Why not just have a `List<ElementNameViewModel>`?

Comment: Not only is it generally considered a very bad idea to extend list, you're reasoning about inheritance *backwards*. Your list is a *more specialized kind of list*; you can't use a *less specialized* list in a context where a *specialized list* is required, the same way that you can't use a Fruit in a context where an Apple is expected. The Fruit might be an orange!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt/21694054#21694054 for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToList()` returns a real `System.Collections.Generic.List` instance, not your `ElementNameList`.

You can cast `ElementNameList` to `IList<ElementNameViewModel>` or to `List<ElementNameViewModel>`, but not the other way.

The reason is because your `ElementNameList` may have a property that the `List<ElementNameViewModel>` doesn't have. What would happen if you try to access that property after the cast?

```
public class ElementNameList : List<ElementNameViewModel> {
    public int X { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<ElementNameViewModel>();
ElementNameList elementList = (ElementNameList) list;
int x = elementList.X; // List<ElementNameViewModel> doesn't have 'X' property, what would happen here?
```

Comment: All great answers and clarified the situation.  I decided to not subclass and have coded `List<ElementNameViewModel>` (as reinforced by @maccettura  comment) in places I was going to have `ElementNameList`

Answer (score 2):

As said in other answers like [Optimistic Peachs'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52634987/10300) and [lmcarreiro's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52634796/10300), the `ToList()` LINQ extension method returns an 
basic `List<T>` object, not an object of your customized `ElementNameList` class.

To solve your immediate problem, I would write it as:

```
var qry = db.Elements
            .Select(c => new ElementNameViewModel
            {
                Symbol = c.Symbol,
                Name = c.Name
            })
            .OrderBy(e => e.Symbol);
var elements = new ElementNameList();
elements.AddRange(qry);
```

I don't have an Visual Studio at hand now to see if I need to 
use `qry.ToList()` in the `AddRange` call, but I believe that
is enough.

By the way, why you had to subclass the list?

Answer (score 1):

Casting to inherited/derived members only goes one way... And that is up the derived hierarchy.

For example:

```
class Animal{
    int number_of_legs;
}
class Cat: Animal{
    string current_sound = "meow";
}
```

If you create an animal (Which should really be abstract in this case, but ignore that) and want to convert it into a cat, and assign that to a variable `mycat` then what would the value stored in `mycat.current_sound` be? It cannot be inferred because `Cat` has all the members that `Animal` has and *more*, so the conversion from `Cat` to `Animal` would make you lose the members that `Cat` has and only be left with the members from `Animal` (Unless you cast it again but that's irrelevant...)

*P.S. I've recently been coding in a different language so pardon my naming of variables and format of my code*